# Making divs stack on top of each other during click through with pure JS

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

http://jsfiddle.net/Zgxv9/

As you can see in my fiddle, my divs go to their natural positions when clicking through them. I need whichever div was clicked last to always appear on top. My current code:

```
function displayOne() {
    document.getElementById("fluid1").style.display = 'block';
}

function displayTwo() {
    document.getElementById("fluid2").style.display = 'block';
}

function displayThree() {
    document.getElementById("fluid3").style.display = 'block';
}
```

I would prefer to avoid jQuery for this if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this.

Move them into a container on click, that way they keep their order, depending on the order in which they were moved into the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zgxv9/1/

```
var target = document.getElementById( "container");

function displayOne() {
    target.appendChild(document.getElementById("fluid1"));
}

function displayTwo() {
    target.appendChild(document.getElementById("fluid2"));;
}

function displayThree() {
    target.appendChild(document.getElementById("fluid3"));
}
```

If you want them to be added to the top you can use insertBefore. It will work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgxv9/7/

```
var target = document.getElementById( "container");

function displayOne() {
    target.insertBefore(document.getElementById("fluid1"), target.firstChild);
}

function displayTwo() {
    target.insertBefore(document.getElementById("fluid2"), target.firstChild);;
}

function displayThree() {
    target.insertBefore(document.getElementById("fluid3"), target.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: I noticed how the correct ones display on the bottom in your example. How do I move them to the top?

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO** — http://jsfiddle.net/Zgxv9/6/

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

function displayOne() {
    var div = document.getElementById("fluid1");
    div.style.display = 'block';
    container.insertBefore(div, container.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insertBefore` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore). Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/Zgxv9/4/).

```
function display(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var id = this.href.split('#')[1],
        div = document.getElementById('fluid' + id),
        divs = document.getElementsByClassName('container-fluid');

    //if current div is not first insert it before the first one
    div !== divs[0] && div.parentNode.insertBefore(div, divs[0]); 
    div.style.display = 'block'; //and show
}

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('toggle'), function(link){
    link.addEventListener('click', display);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The function could be more modular : http://jsfiddle.net/t76BX/58/

```
function displayDiv(elem_id) {
var elem = document.getElementById(elem_id);
elem.style.display = 'block';

var elemCloned = elem.cloneNode(true);
// console.log(elemCloned);

var theparentnode = elem.parentNode;
// console.log(theparentnode);

var divList = document.getElementsByClassName("container-fluid");


var first_element = divList[0];

theparentnode.insertBefore(elemCloned, first_element);
theparentnode.removeChild(elem);
}
```